# pasting to text field from python on Mac

Tags: python, macos, clipboard

Having trouble interacting with the clipboard from python (or pasteboard as mac os calls it) from Python. Running High Sierra.

Found some examples:
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/410615/
http://www.devx.com/opensource/Article/37233/0/page/3

However it seems like they're using deprecated tools that I can't load.

Scrap exists but seems to lack the GetCurrentScrap method:

```
>>> import Carbon.Scrap
>>> from Carbon.Scrap import GetCurrentScrap
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name GetCurrentScrap
>>>
```

Thanks

EDIT

removed part of the question that was erroneous

Comment: `pbpaste` remains in current versions of OS X.  Your code is not using pbaste at all though, so it's not clear what your question there is. For programmatic access, you'll have better luck using pyobjc - http://www.macdrifter.com/2011/12/python-and-the-mac-clipboard.html

Comment: You're right about pbpaste. Something about the virtualenv I was in was causing it to give me those python errors in the 2nd snippet just by calling pbpaste from the bash prompt. However it does work from a clean shell.

However I still have the problem from the from the first snippet, which is that I can't import GetCurrentScrap, and that all the docs about it I can find say its deprecated.

Comment: Read the url I gave you. Carbon anything should give you pause, use pyobjc and cocoa.

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
import subprocess

def getClipboardData():
p = subprocess.Popen(['pbpaste'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
retcode = p.wait()
data = p.stdout.read()
return data

def setClipboardData(data):
p = subprocess.Popen(['pbcopy'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
p.stdin.write(data)
p.stdin.close()
retcode = p.wait()
```